# How fast a 2 stroke engine wears, how much fuel it consumes(compared to a 4-stroke engine) and how to properly mix fuel with oil

Tags: oil, two-stroke

I want to buy a 2 stroke engine to build a minibike. I am 15 years old and i never owned a 2 stroke engine before. I know they wear faster and consume more fuel than a 4 stroke engine. But how fast they wear and how much fuel the consume compared to a 4 stroke engine? I want to buy a 2 stroke engine cuz they are small, more powerful, and cheaper. The fumes annoy me a bit tho. Also, how much oil i have to add in the fuel for each 2 litre tank?What type of 2 stroke engine oil i should add for the first runs?

Im a noob at these stuff and i need help :)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Paulster2 heyyy

Comment: The oil:fuel mix is defined by the manufacturer for each engine. Husquvarna specify 50:1 **but** only if using their oil...

Comment: I know that but i've read in some sites that you should use a different mixture for the first run

Comment: Refer to Husquvarna owners manual, not random internet denizens...

Comment: The engine's manual says: fuel mixture (16:01 / 20:01) Why it has 2 values?It requires another mixture for the first time?

Comment: When properly lubricated, 2-stroke engines don't wear any faster than a similar 4-stroke engine.  2-strokes are designed differently, often with roller bearings on the crankshaft and connecting rod bearings, to allow them to perform with significantly less oil than a 4-stroke.  As far as oiling, it's been mentioned that your best source of information for proper oil ratio and oil type is the manufacturer's instructions.  Follow their break-in procedure as well.

Comment: @jwh20 but why it says 16:01 and 20:01 instead of 16:1 and 20:1??

Comment: As far as I can see, 16:1 = 16:01.  Probably a "translation" issue.  As far as the two different values, I suspect they want you to use 16:1 for the FIRST tankful and then use 20:1 after that.  But the text in the manual should be specific about that somewhere.

Comment: Could you answear all my questions in 1 question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked several questions.

- For a given cubic capacity a 2-stroke engine generates more power and consumes more fuel than a 4-stroke because it fires twice as often.
- They wear more quickly for the same reason: more stress on the moving parts.
- Type of oil: refer to owner's manual.
- The fuel mixture ratio means **in the range** 16/1 to 20/1.
- How much oil in a 2-litre fuel tank? If you fill the tank from empty then 2 litres divided by 16 to 20 is between 100 and 125 ml oil.

Newbie to 2-strokes? The big catch is that they seize up easily and you can find yourself thrown upside down in a ditch. Why? Well, if you are going fast and shut off the power (the fuel supply) you also shut off the oil supply. So a fast revving engine is denied the lubrication it needs. When racing 2-strokes, they sometimes have no air filter so that the driver can put a gloved hand over the air intake and choke the air supply, forcing the carb to supply some fuel and thus some oil.